# Removing permissions with the old model name in DJANGO

Tags: django, django-models, permissions

I changed the name of a model. It was called "Riesgo asociado", I changed it to "Reglas", then to "Regla" and applied the migrations, everything was ok. But now I have change, delete, view and add permissions for each name, even tho they are the same model.

I need to change this because all this permissions are displayed in a custom admin view and those permissions for the old names are useless.

To make it more clear, [see the following image that shows the permissions on the admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcFNb.png) it's the same app_name, same model, different name of the permissions.

This the model "Regla" that was named "Riesgo asociado" and "Reglas" before:

```py
class Regla(AuditMixin, models.Model):
   rule_id = models.IntegerField(
       verbose_name='Rule ID'
   )
   descripcion = models.TextField(
       verbose_name='Descripcion'
   )
   servicio = models.ForeignKey(
       'Servicio',
       on_delete=models.PROTECT,
       verbose_name='Servicio'
   )
   exclusivo = models.BooleanField(
       verbose_name='Exclusivo'
   )
   def __str__(self):
       return str(self.rule_id)
   def get_descripcion(self):
       return str(self.descripcion)
   def get_servicio(self):
       return str(self.servicio)
```

Comment: can you share your model?

Comment: @NalinDobhal I updated the question with the model class

Comment: Have never tried this, but can't you just delete the obsolete Permissions objects? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.Permission (NB I haven't checked the relations so make sure it won't cause a deletion cascade).

Comment: @nigel222 so, getting the permission object and applying a permission.delete() over it? I haven't even consider it, maybe it works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on nigel222's comment, I tried selecting each permission object and doing a permission.delete() over it, and it works! Didn't know you could apply delete() to perms.

I added this for to the view that loaded the permissions:

```py
perms_to_delete= Permission.objects.filter(content_type=ContentType.objects.get_for_model(MyModel))
    for perm in perms_to_delete:
        if "OldModelName" in str(perm):
            perm.delete()
```

Thanks for the idea [nigel222](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5246906/nigel222)!